# In CL Postmodern what :col-type to use for Many to Many field?

Tags: postgresql, lisp, common-lisp

When defining a database access object for use in cl-postmodern, what should the :col-type be for a Many to Many field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that there is no :col-type for a ManyToMany field (as in Django) because a many to many relationship is implemented by creating a new table which is what must be referenced by Postmodern. This is part of the object relational magic which Postmodern doesn't supply.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, how about an integer?